# unexpected output when filtering a particular column with logical expression including LIKE operator

Tags: sqlite

I have the following dataset.

| id | action | source | target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ADD | N/A | /root/dir2.trash |
| 2 | ADD | N/A | /root/dir1 |
| 3 | MOVE | /home/user | /home/user.wasted |
| 4 | MOVE | /usr/bin | /usr/local/bin |
| 5 | MOVE | /usr/sbin | /usr/sbin.trash |

When I run the following query, I am expecting to get row 3 and 5 in response but I get row 1 as well.

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE action = 'MOVE' AND target LIKE '%.wasted' OR target LIKE '%.trash'`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=27af81680cdcbdad19cb058cb5c3f13e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AND` and `OR` act differently than you seem to think, at least in different precedence.
This gets the desired result, probably because it matches how you think.
It makes sure that the first part always has to apply.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE action = 'MOVE' AND ( target LIKE '%.wasted' OR target LIKE '%.trash' )
```

I.e. your original code acted like "(move AND wasted) OR trash".

This is similar to `2 * 3 + 5` being 11, not 16.

Comment: My pleasure. Did you also get why? I tried to explain by probably known example. Let me know if/how I could improve the answer.

Comment: Yep, your explanation makes perfect sense